# Default language highlighting for Python "sub tags"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

Would it be possible for the following tags to "assume" that Python is the default language for a post (in lieu of any other tag - or whatever the rules are...)

**Python 2 series**
[python2](/questions/tagged/python2) [python-2.1](/questions/tagged/python-2.1) [python-2.2](/questions/tagged/python-2.2) [python-2.3](/questions/tagged/python-2.3) [python-2.4](/questions/tagged/python-2.4) [python-2.5](/questions/tagged/python-2.5) [python-2.6](/questions/tagged/python-2.6) [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7)

**Python 3 series**
[python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) [python-3.1](/questions/tagged/python-3.1) [python-3.2](/questions/tagged/python-3.2) [python-3.3](/questions/tagged/python-3.3)

**Tentatively - Python dependant libraries**
[numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas)

May be others - just an idea.

Without an explicit code block or the tag [python](/questions/tagged/python), the posts don't highlight "correctly".

Comment: Theoretically, I think, they _should_ all always be tagged [tag:Python].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [python-x.y](/questions/tagged/python-x.y) tags now have lang-py as the default language.

Comment: Also [tag:numpy] [tag:scipy] [tag:pandas]?